# How to remove text from cell in table by PhpPresentation?

Tags: php, phppresentation

these days I started with PHP-Presentation. I load a presentation and try to remove the value form a cell. But there is no function to clear a cell.

I've just found `addText()` and `createText()`.

```
    public function modTable($slide = null){
        $shapes = $slide->getShapeCollection();

       foreach($shapes as $shape){
           if(get_class($shape) == "PhpOffice\\PhpPresentation\\Shape\\Table") {
              if($shape->getName()){
                    $shape->getRow(1)->getCell(0)->createTextRun("-TEST1-");
                    $shape->getRow(1)->getCell(0)->getParagraph(0)->createText("-TEST2-");

              }
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: 
`$shape->getRow(1)->getCell(0)->setParagraphs(array(new Paragraph()));`

If you have an better solution, feel free to add a comment.